# Need to understand Orchard CMS 2.0 / OrchardCore flow

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, orchardcms

I am trying to understand Orchard CMS 2.0 code flow when running it for the first time i.e. before any UI has rendered or any recipe has been selected by the user. Here is what I know so far:

1. Execution starts in Orchard.Cms.Web, Program.cs, Main method.
2. Asp.NET core framework invokes the Startup class's constructor.
3. ConfigureServices method is called by the Asp.NET core framework. This adds various services to the IServiceCollection.
4. Then some services are configured. e.g. AddManifestDefinition method is called. At this point we get the following popup. We get such a popup multiple items. **I don't know why?**

[image: Source File Changed Popup]

5. At some point all services are added/configured and Asp.NET framework calls the Configure method in Startup class.
6. The last line in this is app.UseModules(). This instructs the code to use middleware classes ModularTenantContainerMiddleware and ModularTenantRouterMiddleware.
7. Then control goes to the 3rd private variable in ModularTenantRouterMiddleware.

[image: Code Flow]

This is confusing in many ways.

8. **Who called this class?** There seems to be no code calling it at this stage.
9. If Asp.NET core framework called it, then **why didn't it call the ModularTenantContainerMiddleware class first**. That was before this class in the pipeline.
10. **Why did the control not come to the other private variables**.
11. The constructor is then called with the next parameter pointing to a method called b__16_0. **How did the next variable come to point to this method? And where exactly is this method?**
12. Control then goes to the highlighted line below.

    - **Who called this and why does it go to the second line** and not the first?
    - It then calls ShellSettingsConfigurationProvider, then ShellSettingsManager. then ExtensionExpanderOptionsSetup, then ManifestOptionsSetup, then ManifestProvider, then FeaturesProvider, then ExtensionProvider... then AmbientExtensionLoader, then TypeFeatureProvider. **How are all these classed being called. Who is calling them?** I don't see any calls to these. If the Asp.NET core framework is calling them, **how is their order determined?**

[image: Code Flow 2]